# Does Logic Pro X require GarageBand's instrument library?

Tags: garageband

I've formerly have GarageBand and its instrument library installed, but since then I have "upgraded" to Logic Pro X and uninstalled GarageBand. Recently I've been running low on storage and found a bunch of music creation files labelled under "GarageBand". I'm wondering whether these files are used by Logic Pro X, or are they just leftover GarageBand files that didn't get deleted? Is it safe to remove them without messing up Logic Pro X?

Comment: Final Cut Pro loops/instructments will show in the storage management page as a GarageBand library, so I'd reason Logic Pro would as well.

Comment: Not the storage management page, it is literally in the /Library/Application Support/GarageBand folder.

Comment: I'm sure what I said still applies - it's a shared resource that goes under the GrarageBand label

Comment: Logic doesn't "need" any of the additional media files. You need to decide whether you *want* them & the functionality they enable - eg sample players. If all you're going to be doing is traditional midi or audio recordings, then those simplistic samples, grooves etc will be extraneous. If, however, you are going to be using it like 'GarageBand Plus' then you will have to keep them.